# Application type for small periodically request on a server

Tags: vb.net, service, server, background

I [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64989864/get-userdomainname-of-user-who-has-a-specifiek-file-in-use-on-shared-network-fol) asked her for help about getting the function `NetFileEnum` working. I need this so that I and my colleagues know who (username) is keeping a specific file open (occupied).
Once it worked I found out that it requires administrator rights, which my colleagues don't have.

So, new plan...
I now want to use this code for a small application to run on the server. This application will then periodically (every 1-5 minutes or so) create an XML-file with the necessary information. This file is then on the share and is searchable by a piece of code with XMLReader on a match.

I just created a Windows Form App (just for trial). I will undoubtedly have to catch all possible errors a little better... but for now it is working. To create a useful XML-file it takes several milliseconds to complete.

```
Option Explicit On

Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Xml

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim ServerName As String = "Testserver01"
        Const MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH As Integer = -1
        Dim dwReadEntries As Integer
        Dim dwTotalEntries As Integer
        Dim pBuffer As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
        Dim pCurrent As FILE_INFO_3 = New FILE_INFO_3()
        Dim dwStatus As Integer = NetFileEnum(ServerName, Nothing, Nothing, 3, pBuffer, MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, dwReadEntries, dwTotalEntries, IntPtr.Zero)

        If dwStatus = 0 Then
            
            Dim document As String = "D:\Share\SharedFolders.xml"

            If File.Exists(document) Then
                Try
                    File.Delete(document)
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            End If

            Dim settings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings With {
                .Indent = True
            }

            Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(document, settings)
                writer.WriteStartDocument()
                writer.WriteStartElement("SharedFolders")
                For dwIndex As Integer = 0 To dwReadEntries - 1
                    Try
                        Dim iPtr As IntPtr = New IntPtr(pBuffer.ToInt64 + (dwIndex * Marshal.SizeOf(pCurrent)))
                        pCurrent = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(iPtr, GetType(FILE_INFO_3)), FILE_INFO_3)

                        writer.WriteStartElement("SharedFolder")
                        writer.WriteElementString("Index", dwIndex.ToString)
                        writer.WriteElementString("PathName", pCurrent.fi3_pathname.ToString)
                        writer.WriteElementString("UserName", pCurrent.fi3_username.ToString)
                        writer.WriteEndElement()

                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
                    End Try
                Next
                writer.WriteEndElement()
                writer.WriteEndDocument()
                writer.Close()
            End Using
            File.SetAttributes(document, FileAttributes.Hidden)
        End If

        If pBuffer <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            Call NetApiBufferFree(pBuffer)
        End If

        File.SetAttributes(FilePath, FileAttributes.Hidden)

        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    <DllImport("Netapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Private Shared Function NetFileEnum(
    ByVal servername As String,
    ByVal basepath As String,
    ByVal username As String,
    ByVal level As Integer,
    ByRef bufptr As IntPtr,
    ByVal prefmaxlen As Integer,
    ByRef entriesread As Integer,
    ByRef totalentries As Integer,
    ByVal resume_handle As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("Netapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Shared Function NetApiBufferFree(ByVal Buffer As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Structure FILE_INFO_3
        Public fi3_id As Integer
        Public fi3_permission As Integer
        Public fi3_num_locks As Integer
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)>
        Public fi3_pathname As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)>
        Public fi3_username As String
    End Structure

End Class
```

2 questions:

1. What is the best way / technique to have my piece of code run every few minutes (using timer, or threads, or using the task manager to run the code every few minutes) without keeping a CPU / thread busy for nothing. Would i be able to run it as some kind of service?
2. What type of project can I best use for this? I'd like to let it run on the background. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 and are a little familiar with VB.NET.

Comment: I'd recommend writing a windows service. It is fairly easy to configure with start and end times and "polling" intervals.

Comment: Thank you very much @AndrewMortimer. It is as easy as you wrote. Working like a charm...